# How to create a style rule for img elements within figure elements (CSS)

Tags: css, html, image, element, figure

Sorry, I know this is a simple question, but I have searched online to try and find this explained and perhaps I'm not asking the question right..

I simply want to know how to create a style rule for img elements within figure elements. I want the rule to apply ONLY to img elements within figure elements. I have literally just begun learning html5 and css and I've hit this speedbump.

Sorry if this question has been answered already, and it likely has, but everything I find is explaining some more advanced program, or shows how to apply this to classes within elements, but 'figure.img {}' or 'img.figure {}' doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Try `figure img { }` or `figure > img {}`. It depends what you exactly want to achieve. The first syntax means any element **img** that is a descendant of element **figure**. The second one matches any *child* **img** of **figure** (immediate descendant).

The `figure.img` would mean a figure which is of class "img".

You can read more about CSS selectors here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was figuring, since so far from what I've seen, . refers to a class. ok well I guess either would work, but I'll use > since the img IS a child. Thank you so much!

Comment: In this case I would always recommend figure > img {} since it's faster than figure img { }